# Динамическое изменение атрибута id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, атрибуты

Есть такой код

```
$("#start").click(function(){

   $(this).attr("id", "submit");

});

$("#submit").click(function(){

   alert("something");

});
```

Вопрос: почему при клике на этот же элемент не выполняется alert? Я ведь изменил ему id на другой, когда первый раз кликнул, следовательно, ожидаю, что выполнятся действия при клике на этот же элемент уже с id "submit", но этого не происходит.

Comment: потому что в момент добавления обработчика элемента с таким id еще не было, поэтому он и не добавился никуда. Кроме того, смена id **не** удаляет уже добавленные обработчики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда вы обрабатываете функцию нажатия для alert, то элемента `#submit` не существует. Нужно добавить глобальный обработчик нажатия на этот элемент:

```js
$("#start").click(function() {
  $(this).attr("id", "submit");
});

$(document).on("click", "#submit", function() {
  alert("something");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Нажми</button>
```

Comment: Вот если бы не ваша кнопка "нажми", то я уже был готов поверить, что вы сами написали этот код :)

Comment: То есть, я правильно понимаю, что код сначала проходит предобработку, в которой вот такие вот несуществующие пока обработчики отбрасываются и даже если потом при клике присвоить элементу айди, на который был прикручен обработчик, динамически он не появится?

Comment: @Muller, правильно

Comment: @MasterAlex, мне лень было писать заново. Но я бы добавил вместо `body` - `document`, так было бы правильней, как по мне

Comment: @Yuri, если правильно писать, то самое быстрое это `$('document.body')`

Comment: @MasterAlex, с чего бы это самое быстрое?

Comment: @Grundy, тут пишут: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/ Хотя я немного неправильно написал, надо без кавычек конечно же

Comment: @MasterAlex, старовата статья

Comment: @Grundy, если статья устарела, то опровержение в студию :)

Comment: у одного меня ощущение, что alert на первый клик - это не что имелось в виду в вопросе?

Comment: @Igor, возможно, но автор доволен :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так работает:

```js
$("#start").click(function() {

  $(this).attr("id", "submit");

});

$("body").on("click", "#submit", function() {

  alert("something");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Нажми</button>
```

Comment: Простите, что стырил ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#start").click(function(){

   $(this).attr("id", "submit");
  
  $(this).click(function(){

   alert("something");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  <div id="start">start</div>
```

Comment: и на каждый клик добавлять **еще** один обработчик?